# Sample red5 code

Tags: actionscript, red5

I want very sample code for make chat (Text only, no streaming ...)

This code is like what I want to looking for in actionscript for clientside and java for serverside:

**Server Side**

```
function receiveMsg(data){
    toClient("Server says" + data);
}
```

**CLient Side**

```
btn.event(click, function(){
    toServer("Hello Server");
}
```

That's all! thanks in advence

Comment: From what I've read, the Red5 download includes an example of a simple chat application.

Answer (score 1):

It may be more than what you want, but it is certainly a simple chat app. I wrote a blog post and demo code for a clustered chat app in Red5; feel free to do with it what you like.
http://blog.infrared5.com/2011/07/clustering-with-red5/